# C++ How does a multi-dimensional vector grow internally?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

Consider a two-dimensional vector with integers, but initially only with one element:

```
std::vector< std::vector <int> > vec( 1, std::vector<int>( 1, 0 ) );
```

Now I want to make the vector in both dimensions larger, so that the vector results always in a m x m matrix.

Will the following two commands do that:

```
vec.push_back( std::vector<int> );
vec[0].push_back( 0 );
```

or will just the first row and respectively the first column increase by an element?

Comment: It is just a vector which contains other vectors. So if you figure out how a vector works, you have your answer.

Comment: If you want a dynamic, rectangular, multidimensional array, use a class which is made for that.  e.g. something from [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).  A vector of vectors is a poor substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first row will enlarge. The fact the vectors are all grouped together doesn't make them enlarge together.

Comment: Thank you! Do I have touse for-loops with push_back() to achieve a m x m matrix every time, or is there any vector method which does exactly that?

Comment: @fotinsky you can instantiate the thing to be m*m: `std::vector< std::vector <int>> vec(m, std::vector<int>(m));`

Comment: With `std::vector< std::vector <int>> vec(m, std::vector<int>(m));` all entries of vec will point to the same vector. Is that really wanted?

Comment: @user2708138: What do you mean by "point"?  There is no pointer in that declaration.  It creates a vector, with `m` distinct vectors, each with `m` distinct integers.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley & juanchopanza: You are right. My bad. The vectors inside of vec are copy constructed from `std::vector<int>(m)`. So it behaves like wanted. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a vector of vectors, you will need to increase every row if you want the width of every row to increase....

Answer (score 1):

A vector is a single dimensional container - the details of the contents are abstracted. That means, vector is supposed to know nothing about it's contents.

```
std::vector< TYPE >
```

Coincidentally, this means that you can use a sub-container that also overloads `operator[]`, but don't mistake that for `vector` *itself* supporting [][].

```
std::vector< std::map< std::string, std::string > > foo;
foo[1]["hello"];
```

is basically

```
std::map& fooMap = foo[1];
fooMap["hello"];
```

There's no special case for vector